# How to show the vertical bar on the left side of code block in Visual Studio? (see the figure to get the idea)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

## Screenshot

[image]

## Question

I noticed some people can show the left bar as shown above.

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a very useful free add-on for Visual Studio called CodeRush Express which will do this.

http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2009/06/25/coderush-xpress-for-c-and-visual-basic-2008.aspx  (Scroll to the 'Structural Highlighting' bit to see a screenshot of it).

http://www.codekana.com/ is another add-on that does a similar thing.